# Area of rectangular tv screen from aspect ratio

Tags: geometry

[image]

I need to compare compare quantity $A$ with $B$ i.e is $A>B$ or $A<B$ or they are equal, or can't determine.

### My solution:

$(3a)^2 + (4a)^2 = 25^2$
or, $25 a^2= 625$
or, $a= 5$

so, $3a*4a = 12*25= 300$

similarly solving from 2nd ratio,

$(9b)^2 + (16b)^2 = 25^2$
so, $b= 25/\sqrt{337}$

so, $9b*16b= 144* 625/337 = 267.06$ (approximately)

So, quantity $A$ is greater.

#### any smart solution?

Comment: It is not that tedious is it? By the way the actual diagonal length is irrelevant (all that matters is that the diagonals are the same).

Comment: as square's area is biggest, among rectangles with fixed perimeter. can we conclude in this case, ratio which is closer to 1 will have bigger area (as diagonal is fixed, can we assume perimeter is also fixed in some way). though i am finding this is true for different ratio, but can't find logic behind it

Comment: Yes, you are right the area will be largest when the aspect ratio is $1$, i.e. when the TV is square. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d$ be the square of the length of the diagonal, and $h$ and $w$ be, respectively, the squares of the height and width of the TV. Now $$w=d-h.$$ The area of the TV is higher, the higher is the square of the area of the TV,
$$hw=h(d-h)$$

This expression is concave in $h$ and has maximizer $h=d/2$, i.e. where $w=h$. So the closer is $h$ to $w$, i.e the closer is the apsect ratio to $1$, the larger the area of the TV, given a fixed diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed perimeter or fixed diagonal, a square has the maximum area. Out of the 2 rectangles, the one with aspect ratio 3:4 is more nearer to a square shape. Hence it has the maximum area.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Your answer says essentially what is said in the accepted answer but without a proof. I suggest that you add some more information to make it more interesting.

Comment: A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).